# unable to get result showing Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i want get last record of table with particular column value. after that i need to increment value ..here table is empty and column propery is string

```
     public async Task<string> GetLastBillNo()
            {
                return this.DbSet.LastOrDefault().CustomOrderNumber;
            } // getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object”
```

bs logic is

```
 long billNo = 0;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(await invoiceRepository.GetLastBillNo()))
                    {
                        billNo = long.Parse(await invoiceRepository.GetLastBillNo());
                        billNo = billNo + 1;
                        order.CustomOrderNumber = billNo.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                        order.CustomOrderNumber = (billNo + 1).ToString();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is `DbSet`? Is there any record in this dbset?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the null Object reference before incrementing the next value.

```
        public async Task<string> GetLastBillNo()
        {
            return (this.DbSet.LastOrDefault() != null ? this.DbSet.LastOrDefault().CustomOrderNumber : string.Empty);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is order class static ?
Else, You need to instantiate the order object. It does not exist inside the context.

Comment: no TropicalViking its an entity ..its contain one of the filed "CustomOrderNumber "

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var order = new YourDBContext()) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(await invoiceRepository.GetLastBillNo()))
                {
                    billNo = long.Parse(await invoiceRepository.GetLastBillNo());
                    billNo = billNo + 1;
                    order.CustomOrderNumber = billNo.ToString();
                }
                else
                    order.CustomOrderNumber = (billNo + 1).ToString();
...rest of your code
    }
```